# Laravel/php function variables wrongly alternating

Tags: php, laravel, internationalization, laravel-routing

I am i18n the routes of my site, I want to have a url structure that contains the language short code and I want the routes to work without the short codes as well (which will default to English)

I am trying to achieve `mysite.com/articles/1/some-post-title` (Default to english)
then `mysite.com/fr/articles/1/some-post-title` (choose appropriate language, in this case French)

I have two routes one without the locale variable and the other without the local variable. This two routes are pointing to the same function

## In Case 1

where the locale variable is absent my code instead assigns the id value from the route to the `$locale` variable(which is supposed to be null) then the `$title` variable to assigned to `$id` making the code return wrong results.

```
Route::get('/articles/{id}/{title}', function($locale=null,$id=null, $title=null){
  return $locale.'<br>'.$id.'<br>'.$title;
});
```

## In Case 2

The right order is followed since all three variables are present

```
Route::get('/{locale}/articles/{id}/{title}',function($locale=null,$id=null, $title=null){
  return $locale.'<br>'.$id.'<br>'.$title;
});
```

**Another worry**

Even in case two the code will misbehave if I changed the order of the variables and maybe put local at the end, Even though am not sure how php handles this I don't think the order should matter since these variable have unique names. 
I know I could point the routes to two different functions as a possible solution but that would just be repeating code.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think of `null` as a state, not a value. As a value it often doesn't transport well. `foo.com//a` vs `foo.com/0/a`. Not sure I fully got the question but is that basically what is happening?

Comment: @ficuscr well in this case the null value is assigned in the function not the level of the route.

Comment: @ficuscr the first route is completely void of the locale variable so the null value wont result to "//"

Answer (score 2):

The order of routes matters. So to make sure the valid actions should be matched you might consider adding [routes constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints), for example:

```
Route::get('/{locale}/articles/{id}/{title}',function($locale=null,$id=null, $title=null){
  return $locale.'<br>'.$id.'<br>'.$title;
})->where('id','\d+');
```

to make sure id is really number.

About parameters order, Laravel will match parameters in the order they appear. No matter that you have 3 parameters in your closure if you have only 2 of them in your route, so for this snippet:

```
Route::get('/articles/{id}/{title}', function($locale=null,$id=null, $title=null){
```

`id` parameter will go to 1st variable (`$locale`) and `title` parameter will go to 2nd variable (`$id`). There is no 3rd parameter in url, so nothing will be assigned to title. If you have 2 parameters in your url, you should use same number of them in closure to make it work as expected.

Comment: I understand that the order of the variables in the route matters, why in the function? Adding the constraints you specified did not improve the behavior. Thanks for your response so far

Comment: @F.ENoelNfebe I've updated my answer with extra explanation